# SWT Unsatisfied link error in compiled JAR

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, swt

I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA trying to create a build artifact for an application that has some legacy SWT components.

I've included a compiled Windows SWT JAR in the class path of the main application's JAR. However, every time it is run and an SWT component needs to be loaded, i get the following stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
    no swt-gtk-3557 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
```

As far as I've seen from other answers, It would seem like I am using the SWT jar for Linux but I know for a fact that this is not the case.

I've tried adding it to the class path with intellij and compiling it in to the main jar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if anymore information is required, let me know and I will do my best to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

The project had a Linux SWT in one of the other library folders that was taking precedence over the windows one. Once I removed that, it worked perfectly.